# Angularjs Multiple JSONP call with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am trying to integrate yelp api in my angular app.

```
 var params = {
        callback: 'angular.callbacks._0',
        location: 'San+Francisco',
        oauth_consumer_key: 'xxxxxxx', //Consumer Key
        oauth_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', //Token
        oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
        oauth_nonce: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
        term: 'Itailian',
        limit: 5
      };
      var consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      var tokenSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
      function generateSignature(method, yelpURL, params, consumerSecret, tokenSecret) {
    return oauthSignature.generate(method, yelpURL, params, consumerSecret, tokenSecret, {encodeSignature: false});
  }
    params['oauth_signature'] = generateSignature(method, yelpURL, params, consumerSecret, tokenSecret);


//Doest work even if I push below call in array and then do $q.all(promisesArra).

var defered = $q.defer();
        $http.jsonp(yelpURL, {params: params})
          .success(function (data) {
            defered.resolve(data);
            $localStorage[cusine] = data;
          })
          .error(function (error) {
            console.log('failed', error);
          });
        return defered.promise;
```

I want to make multiple calls for different terms example : Italian, Mexican,..
I can make one jsonp call but not multiple.

I am not sure about the issue .I guess it is because callback in angular is hard coded and can be only angular.callbacks._0

Comment: try using `.then` instead of `.success`

Answer (score 0):

`$http.jsonp` already returns a promise, so there is no need to use `$q.defer()`. In addition, `$http.success` and `$http.error` as been [depreciated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/docs/api/ng/service/$http) since v1.4.4. Instead, use `then()` to resolve you promise:

```
$http.jsonp(yelpURL, params).then(
          function (data) { // successcallback                
            $localStorage[cusine] = data;
          }, function (error) { // errorcallback
            console.log(error);
          });
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saarmstrong/hYACX/8/light/